# How to fetch 35 character onwards in a file using python

Tags: python-2.7

File contains some text data want to get character 35th character onwards

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for the seek function of a file:

```
 f = open('data.txt','r')
 f.seek(34) 
 print f.read()
```

Comment: I'm afraid I will need at least the error message and much more helpful would be an example of the data.